# Array - Eliminate all duplicates C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, duplicates

I have the following array

```
a[0]=4, a[1]=6, a[2]=9, a[3]=4, a[4]=4 ...
```

I want to eliminate all duplicate values from the array and print the array.
So the array `4 6 9 4 4` would become `4 6 9`

I've written my code like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        if(frec[a[i]]>1) //see if there are duplicate values in frequency array.
        {
            for(int j=i;j<=n-1;j++)
                a[i]=a[i+1];
            frec[a[i]]--;
            n=n-1;
        }
    }
```

However instead of `4 6 9` i get `6 6 9`. Thank you.

Edit: full code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

void readarray(int a[], int frec[],const int &n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        cout<<"a["<<i<<"]=";
        cin>>a[i];
        frec[a[i]] += 1;
    }
}

void printarray(int a[], int frec[], const int &n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<UCHAR_MAX;i++)
        cout<<frec[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
}

void eliminareduplicate(int a[],int frec[], int &n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
        if(frec[a[i]]>1)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<=n-1;j++)
                a[i]=a[i+1];
            frec[a[i]]--;
            n=n-1;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
   int a[100], frec[UCHAR_MAX]={0}, n;
   cout<<"n= "; cin>>n;
   readarray(a,frec,n);
   eliminareduplicate(a,frec,n);
   printarray(a,frec,n);
}
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `std::set`? If so, I'd go with that.

Comment: Please paste complete code...

Comment: Use `std::vector<int>`. you cannot _remove_ elements from raw arrays, unless you rearrange copies of the existing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is a typo error:

```
   if(frec[a[i]]>1)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<=n-1;j++)
            a[i]=a[i+1];     // <===== USE j not i !  
     ....
```

However, the result will be that the first duplicates will be removed, and only the last occurence is kept (because you remove the items if their frequency is greater than 1, which is no longer the case when all the previous occurences were removed).

If you prefer that the first occurence is kept, but the remaining ones removed, here a variant of your original algorithm:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
{
    if (frec[a[i]] > 1) //if there are duplicate values in frequency array.
    {
        int m = 0;      // number of items removed 
        for (int j = i + 1, k = i + 1; j <= n - 1; j++) // start looping from next
            if (a[j] != a[i])    // if it's not one of the duplicate,
                a[k++] = a[j];   // copy it
            else m++;            // otherwhise don't copy it, and icrease items not copied. 
        frec[a[i]] -= m; 
        n -= m;
    }
}
```

*I don't know if this is relevant for you, but for each duplicate your version moves all elements following the n-th occurence n-1 times, whereas this variant moves them only once.*

*You'll also notice that this variant can work without using your frequency table at all (except, that it will systematically loop through the remaining items, instead of doing so only for the duplicates).*

Answer (score 0):

One thing for sure is this is a worst program you could design to detect/remove duplicates in array. That's because size of your frec array depends on the numbers in the array.

So, better option is to go for std::set

OR

if you don't want ordering among elements then you can choose hash-table implementation for this.

Comment: The issue with "better" alternatives is that they require ordering.  If you iterate through your set it's ordered, and you don't know if the order is important for OP or not.

Comment: @Christophe First that's why I mentioned "if you don't want standard way". And in any case do you think using another array to store count of elements in one array is a option.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. I do not need to use the frec array. If there is an duplicate element in the array I will ignore it and reduce the size of my original array.

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (j = i + 1; j < size;) {
         if (a[j] == a[i]) {
            for (k = j; k < size; k++) {
               a[k] = a[k + 1];
            }
            size--;
         } else
            j++;
      }
}
```

To print the array:

```
 for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      std::cout << a[i] << " ";
 }
```